# jQuery Cycle Lazy Loading

Tags: jquery, cycle

I have a jQuery cycle presentation page that contains about 48 slides.  The problem is that initial load of all the assets takes a while so the page looks distorted for about 1-5 seconds.  Is there a way to lazy load the assets needed by each slide only when the slide is called or the slide is known to be the previous or next slide?

Answer (score 5):

The jquery cycle2 plugin allows for progressive loading:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/progressive.php

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow auto" 
    data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
    data-cycle-timeout="2000"
    data-cycle-caption=".caption1"
    data-cycle-caption-template="{{slideNum}} / 9"
    data-cycle-loader="true"
    data-cycle-progressive="#images"
    >
    <!-- only one image declared in markup -->
    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/beach1.jpg">

    <!-- 
        JSON array of slides to be loaded progressively,
        nested inside a script block.  The script block does not need
        to be inslide the slideshow container, it can be anywhere on the
        page.  Note the type on the script tag.
    -->
    <script id="images" type="text/cycle">
[
    "<img src='http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/beach2.jpg'>",
    "<img src='http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/beach3.jpg'>",
    ...
    "<img src='http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/beach9.jpg'>"
]
</script>
</div>
<div class="center caption1"></div>
```